# For each cell in range, if cell value is not blank then vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to get the below code to function due to Run-time error '1004': Application-define or object-defined error.

Usually when I've encountered this error is was due to sheet protection, I've ensured sheets are unprotected thus the line at the start of the sub.

I'll outlay the scenario here and the end goal:

**Sheet1 = Live Contracts**

This sheet contains a table of 6 columns and dynamic number of rows.
column 1 contains a contract reference number. Columns 2 - 6 are irrelevant to this.

**Sheet 4 = Contract Sums**

This sheet contains all contracts, the corresponding department and the value of the contract.

**Goal**

Create a module which can be called via a userform button.

The module needs to view column A of sheet1 and for each cell -if there is a value- create a vlookup in column G with the following parameters.

```
Lookup Value = Cell.offset(0, -6)

Table array = Sheet4.range("A3:C676")

Col_Index_Num = 1

FALSE - Exact match
```

The module would need to repeat this process for all cells within the range.

Now for what I've produced:

```
 Worksheets("Live Contracts").Unprotect

Dim rng As range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cell As range
Dim contractrange As range

'Find dynamic range
lastrow = Worksheets("Live Contracts").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set contractrange = Worksheets("Contract Sums").range("A3:C676")
Set rng = Worksheets("Live Contracts").range("A2:A" & lastrow)

For Each cell In rng
'If cell does not equal blank then for each cell in column A, offset to column G.
    If cell.Value <> "" Then

    'In column G, vlookup column A cell value in contractrange's column C, only return exact match
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Application.VLookup(cell.Offset(0, -6), contractrange, 1, False)

        'In column H, vlookup column A cell value in contractrange's column A, only return exact match
        cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(cell.Offset(0, -7), contractrange, 3, False)
    End If
    'Repeat for all cells in range
Next cell


End Sub
```

The first line beginning with cell.offset is being highlighted when debugging

P.S I'm relatively new to VBA, apologies for poor code!

Comment: Do you not also get an error since `lastrow` is being used before it is defined?  I believe the error 1004 is because you haven't defined `contractsum`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've moved lastrow up to before set rng. I'll edit the original post

Comment: Thanks Jarom, Seems like I'm full of mistakes today! I had defined contractrange, but had used the term contractsum within the formula. I have changed the formula over to the correct defined range, but still receiving the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, actually the main issue is probably that you are in column A and you are trying to go to the left by using `cell.offset(0,-6)`  You can only offset to the right of column A.

Comment: I think I found out why you are trying to use the offset in the vlookup.  See my answer and let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe my answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490109/for-each-cell-in-range-if-cell-value-is-not-blank-then-vlookup) may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be mixing up the use of active cells and the `Cell` that you are using in your loop.  The `Cell` will only change after a full loop iteration.  It is not like an active cell that will change after you select a different cell.

So when you use `Cell.offset(0,6)`, the `Cell` has not changed, so you don't need to try to get back by using `Cell.offset(0,-6)` in the Vlookup.

Try this instead:

```
For Each cell In rng
'If cell does not equal blank then for each cell in column A, offset to column G.
    If cell.Value <> "" Then

    'In column G, vlookup column A cell value in contractrange's column C, only return exact match
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Application.VLookup(cell, contractrange, 1, False)

        'In column H, vlookup column A cell value in contractrange's column A, only return exact match
        cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(cell, contractrange, 3, False)
    End If
    'Repeat for all cells in range
Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, many thanks for your help Jarom. I can see where I was going wrong now